# FFmpeg text box padding using boxborderw

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to overlay a text on a video using FFmpeg 6.0 `drawtext` filter.
In the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Syntax) it says:

> **boxborderw:** Set the width of the border to be drawn around the box using boxcolor. The value must be specified using one of the following formats:
>
> - `boxborderw=10|20` - set the width of the top and bottom borders to 10 and the width of the left and right borders to 20

However, when I try to use this format to have different horizontal and vertical padding with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Countdown %{eif\:10-t\:d}':box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=20|80:fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=w-text_w-10:y=10:enable='between(t,3,10)'" -c:a copy output_video.mp4
```

I get the following error:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x600000b04000] Unable to parse option value "20|80"
```

Couldn't find anywhere a working example using this piped format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available since version 6.1.